# Calling a batch file from another does not returns

Tags: batch-file

#### Hi, I am working in a batch project here i got a problem.

These are my scripts!

::Main.bat

```
@echo off
echo Start
hello
echo Ends
pause
```

::hello.bat

```
@echo off
echo Hi I am working
```

#### ::Output

```
Start
Hi I am Working
```

### I want the output should be like this

#### ::Output

```
Start
Hi I am Working
Stop
```

Please Help Me Do so

I tried using ***call*** but i don't want to edit my Main.bat
I can only effort to edit hello.bat

Comment: In batch you need the keyword **`call`** to return to the caller, otherwise you **`run`** the batch without leaving a return address on the call stack and thus can't **`return`**

Comment: Why You Did not Merge All Bat ???